# Discord py How to add role by name not id

Tags: python, discord.py

How to add role by name not id. group is string

```
await message.author.add_roles(message.author, group)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.find) function for this:

```
role_name = "role"  # specify role name here
role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=role_name)
if role is not None:
    await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I delete a person's previous roles?I use `async def on_message(message):`